# rake doesn't work, missing gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, rake

My rake function don't work anymore

```
$rake routes
Could not find sass-rails-4.0.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

when i run `bundle install`, it says:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/kaibakker/dewortel/vendor/bundle/bin/ri
An error occurred while installing rdoc (3.12.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rdoc -v '3.12.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

`sudo bundle install` works fine

I already un- and reinstalled gem `sass`

Its probably a simple problem (i am new to rails)

Thanks in advance

System (OSX 10.7, rails 4.0.1, ruby 2.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I fixed it, pretty simple solution after all:
move `vender/bundle` to the trash and run `bundle install`.